# Can't find my disk partitions. Ubuntu Installer

Tags: partitioning, usb-installation

I am trying to dual boot windows alongside with Ubuntu. But while installing I couldn't find my disk partitions and the available free space in the disk.

[Partition table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6p3w.jpg!)

[gdisk -l /dev/nvme0n1 Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0EPZ.jpg)

Comment: I think you should research how to repair your damaged GPT header before installing another OS.

Comment: I would investigate how to make a gparted book disk/usb and let us know what partitions it finds.

Comment: Your gdisk output shows a lot of errors. But do not know if that is because it is trying to read a Intel RST drive. Have you converted Windows & UEFI setting to AHCI? Be sure that is done before running other gpt partition fixes. https://superuser.com/questions/1672500/ubuntu-installation-with-intel-rst?noredirect=1#comment2565531_1672500  &  repair gpt:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html